# Someone just told me that my business website structure should be "well-siloed"... what does that mean.

Tags: metaphors

I know they're referencing a silo but i'm not understanding how it correlates/translates to business structure and presentation. are they talking about the function of the silo?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_silo

Comment: It looks like you got some fairly good answers, but this question probably really belongs on one of the IT-related stacks.

Answer (score 3):

They are telling you to keep different parts of your business separate.

The silo metaphor works because the reason for separate silos (instead of one big one) was that if one silo of grain went bad, the others would hopefully be ok.

I'm surprised to hear someone recommending silos. In IT at least, silos are generally looked upon unfavorably, as teams become too entrenched in their specialty and do not communicate enough with other teams.

Comment: It's certainly not an unknown usage in the context of IT security, as evidenced by [*gaps can occur between **siloed security systems**, and these gaps are exploited by criminals*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22siloed+security+systems%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)